# Kids activity web app/solution

Tags: web-apps

I'm managing a kids activity group. I'm looking for a solution to track the members. Their status etc.

Some requirements:

- Web based. Preferably, self-hosted
- Parents need to be able to log in and manage their child's/children's data
- Siblings get a discount so I need to be able to identify them
- Children loan equipment so we need to track that
- Multiple adults have different roles so they need to be able to log in and manage the assigned aspect of the organisation. Ex. to hand out or receive equipment.
- There are several sub-groups the children can join within our organization. A child can be a member of one or more of these.
- It would be great if the solution had a way of enforcing workflows for different procedures. For instance, when a child joins, insurance need to be set up, equipment loaned out, training sessions planned and so on. If the solution has some sort of task management and workflow, that would be great.

I know I'm asking a lot but, hey, there are some great web apps out there and I'm thinking I'm not the only one dealing with this kind of a problem.

Today we're using a combination of Excel, Dropbox, e-mail and so on. It's a pain to manage and a lot of manual labor is needed to keep the wheels running.

If anyone has ideas on solutions I can use, that would be great.

Comment: What do you mean by children joining an organization? <sup>Note: I don't have 50 reputation so I can't comment :( this is now an answer btw</sup>

Comment: Old request, but did you get this resolved? If so, please what solution did you go for? If not, what kind of equipment do they loan? Is it daily or hourly loans? What kind of activity takes place in the subgroups, or are they just online forums?

Comment: @ZZ No, it was never resolved. We're using a combination of Nextcloud, Excel and Wordpress. Not perfect but we manage. I'm still looking...

Answer (score 1):

You can create a solution for this using [Drupal CMS](https://www.drupal.org):

- It is web-based, opensource, and you can self-host.
- You can create a "Content type" for "Child" and add the various fields you want. Siblings can be linked using the [Entity Reference](https://www.drupal.org/project/entityreference) module.
- For loaning equipment you could probably use the [Merci](https://www.drupal.org/project/merci) module or one of the others.
- For sub-groups you can the [Organic Groups](https://www.drupal.org/project/og) or [Group](https://www.drupal.org/project/group) modules.
- There are also a couple of modules to enforce workflows e.g. [Workflow](https://www.drupal.org/project/workflow).
- Using the in-built roles, parents can manage children's data. Also other users can be given appropriate permissions to perform various roles.

It will require some understanding and configuration to put it all together, to make it work the way you want.